# How to create a filter with Taxonomy Categories in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, taxonomy

I need to create a filter with Wordpress Taxonomy Categories and its Posts like this picture[image: question]
Name, Issuer,Isin and Market place dropdowns are categories.How I can separate categories and create a simple filter with their posts?I searched more but didnt know how to manage and where to start.Tried the plugin [Beautiful taxonomy filters](https://wordpress.org/plugins/beautiful-taxonomy-filters/installation/) but it didnt that what I need with separate categories.
Help me please with this.
I am geting the dropdowns like this way

```
function get_terms_dropdown($taxonomies, $args){
                                    $myterms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
                                    $output ="<select class='news_cat'>";
                                    foreach($myterms as $term){
                                        $root_url = get_bloginfo('url');
                                        $term_taxonomy=$term->taxonomy;
                                        $term_slug=$term->slug;
                                        $term_name =$term->name;
                                        $link = $root_url.'/?'.$term_taxonomy.'='.$term_slug;
                                        $output .="<option value='".$link."'>".$term_name."</option>";
                                    }
                                    $output .="</select>";
                                return $output;
                                }
                    $taxonomies = array('articles-tax');
                    $args = array('orderby'=>'count','hide_empty'=>false);
                    echo get_terms_dropdown($taxonomies, $args);
```

and created a form like this way

```
 <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">and dropdowns here</form>
```

but still cant get and see in url this all selected dropdown valus, help me pls to fix this, This is my first step in filter world!

Answer (score 0):

Pass all the term `name` or `slug` on the URL on `SEARCH` button. Get the QUERY_STRING and search for the Term ID with the [get_term_by](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) function:

```
// Suppose you have term name in URL
// Then find Term ID with Name, or if you have slug in url then change "name" to "slug"
$term = get_term_by( "name", $term_name, $taxonomy );
//$term->term_id;
```

Now you have to use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) to access the posts by specific term ids :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'YOUR_POST_TYPE',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
          'field' => 'id',
          'terms' => $term->term_id // You can pass more then one term id like array(32, 65)
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: What you mean saying pass all the taxonomy name on the url @jogesh_pi?

Comment: @AnahitGhazaryan oops its a typo mistake, its term name

Comment: So for example I got this categories in the dropdown and styled them after it what I should do @jogesh_pi?

Comment: @AnahitGhazaryan, for dropdown you have to use <select name="_name"> html tag, so in option set `<option value="term_slug">term_name</option>` same thing for rest dropdowns but have to change the `<select name="_issuer">`, `<select name="_isn">` etc.

Comment: then on submit you will get the url like `?_name=term_slug&_issuer=term_slug&_isn=term_slug` then detect it through `$_GET` or any preferred method and apply according to codes

Comment: I am getting the dropdowns like this way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72026/discussion-between-anahit-ghazaryan-and-jogesh-pi).